# Visual studio -MVC3 Debug error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I get this error, some times, when I try to debug the asp,net MVC3 Web application. What should i do to get rid of error. I cannot find any logs in eventviewer. Its kind of annoying when you show the demo to a client and this kind of thing happens.

[image]

How do fix this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910029/asp-net-mvc-debugger-throwing-sehexception

Comment: Google "SEHException" because that the exception that you are getting. Also click on view Details and see if you can get more info.

Comment: Visit http://forums.asp.net/t/1704958.aspx/7/10?Re+SEHException+thrown+when+I+run+the+application you can check this on your side and try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall/remove Trusteer Rapport and it will work fine :)
ref: http://forums.asp.net/t/1704958.aspx/8/10?Re%20SEHException%20thrown%20when%20I%20run%20the%20application