# External Component has thrown an exception: Visual Studio 2010: SEHException: what causes it?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I got this error message (External Component has thrown an exception)  when debugging a project.  It started all of a sudden yesterday afternoon.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Ask the question and answer it. That would be better than posting an answer as a question.

Comment: If you think that this post is not going to be useful to anyone then by all means vote it down.  I thought I was doing a service to the developer community out there by posting this, but if that's the response I get from someone with a gazillion reputation points then I'll reconsider being community minded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SEHException was unhandled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909795/sehexception-was-unhandled)

Comment: He's not telling you that there's anything wrong with sharing information. He's telling you that **questions** are reserved for, well, *questions*, not answers or useful tidbits. If you want to self-answer a question, do as the FAQ says and pretend that you're on Jeopardy: Ask a question and then answer it. Please be community minded by following community norms. There's a good reason for all of them.

Comment: Peter - the way SO works is by asking and answering a question (2 separate things). We expect this format to be adhered to as part of the norm. It is absolutely acceptable to ask a question and answer it yourself, but answering the question in the body of the question is not how we do things here. I was trying to give you a pointer regarding usage of SO.

Comment: As it happens, it is a duplicate of the question that Cody Gray suggested.  I did a search before posting and couldn't find that original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied the advice in http://forums.asp.net/t/1704958.aspx/7/10?Re+SEHException+thrown+when+I+run+the+application (i.e. uninstall Trusteer Rapport) and now it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as Peter, and couldn't work out what on earth was the matter until I checked http://forums.asp.net/p/1704958/4537086.aspx/1?Re+SEHException+thrown+when+I+run+the+application.  Trusteer have now released an update ( download it from the link above) and this seems to have fixed the problem.