# Visual Studio 2010 giving error "External Component has thrown an exception"

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am running Visual Studio Ultimate on Windows 7. Here is the description of my problem:

- My VS 2010 had been running absolutely fine until today when it started giving error "**External Component has thrown an exception**" when I try to open a new website. Creating a new web application works fine though but I am unable to run any of them.
- While trying to run the previously created websites/webapps, its giving error as "**Unable to launch ASP.NET development server**".
- And when I try to debug the website/web app, I am getting error: "Unable to launch ASP.NET development server. **An attempt was made to perform an initialization operation when initialization has already been completed**".
- Similar errors are coming when I try to open Windows Form Applications and other projects.
- No errors are getting logged on event viewer and I cannot see any other error information apart from what is mentioned above.

I searched all over internet but no help. I have already trying un-installing VS2010 using the script at this [link](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4321) (provided by MS). But when I re-install VS2010, it still shows me same error. To my surprise, after re-installing VS still shows the previous project list in "Recent Projects". I really doubt if VS is getting uninstalled.

I am totally clueless and any help would be highly appreciated. I am left with no other option but to format my OS if I don't find a solution here :( Please do let me know if any other details are required...

Comment: Did you try the suggestion here yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910869/external-component-has-thrown-an-exception-visual-studio-2010-sehexception-wh

Comment: Yes, I had already visited that link and verified that I don't have any software running with name "Trusteer". I did a program search on my machine and it returned nothing. Also verified the directory they mention in Q&A and none of that exist on my system

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by an adding or extension that you've installed, maybe without being aware of. 
there are several ways to deal with that - one is to get inside add in manager and remove/ deactivate them. 
if VS can't load there is a flag that should do the trick.

check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx) for instructions on devenv flags.

you can use: /ResetAddin  or /SafeMode

Comment: Thanks Dani for quick reply. I just verified that I have no Add-ins installed on my VS. If at all there was an Add-in previously,  re-installation of VS might have removed them all. My VS is as fresh as 2 hour baby now.