# Libreoffice 5.0.3 version throws me an error while recording in studio

Tags: visual-studio, libreoffice

while i am Recording libre office impress in studio.it shows me an error like 
"External component has thrown an exception" in win 8 and win 10 but it is working fine in win 7..Latest version libre office installed is 5.0.3...can any 1 help me resolve this problem

Comment: Please edit your question to show the full error message and relevant source code.  Delete the [newer duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715701/sehexception-was-unhandled-by-user-code-in-uno-util-bootstrap-bootstrap), because it does not have any answers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is an error that [sometimes occurs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e4d1cac-fa5b-4660-9c68-3a49747b1845/external-component-has-thrown-an-exception?forum=vsautotest) for [action recordings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286647.aspx).

If you used an earlier version of LibreOffice in win 7, then try using that version on win 8 and 10.  LO 5.0.3 is not as stable as some 4.x versions.

Also check what version of visual studio are you using, and whether is it different from what you used on win 7.

What action does it fail to record?  If it gets stuck on a particular action, then perhaps there is a different way to achieve the same results.

Possibly related: [External Component has thrown an exception: Visual Studio 2010: SEHException: what causes it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910869/external-component-has-thrown-an-exception-visual-studio-2010-sehexception-wh)