# How identify UNC Access in HttpModule

Tags: c#, http, sharepoint

I have an HttpModule for a web application I use (SharePoint).
I want to be able to identify when a file is being viewed through UNC (\Server\Something).
The Request.Url.IsUnc always returns false, and the call always shows "http://", even though a user tried to browse the directory through UNC.

Is there any way do be able to identity UNC access?

Answer (score 3):

Per: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.isunc.aspx

The IsUnc property is true if the specified Uri instance is a UNC path (such as \server\folder or file://server/folder). This property always returns true if the URI has the file:// scheme and specifies a host component.

Therefore, if the call always shows "http://", IsUnc will not identify it.

If that doesn't help, there are some alternative methods defined in this post:
[Easiest way in C# to find out if an app is running from a network drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633680/easiest-way-in-c-sharp-to-find-out-if-an-app-is-running-from-a-network-drive)

Comment: No, what I meant is I click Start--> run --> and then \\Server\File1.docx.  The HTTPModule intercepts the request, but the URL is http://Server/File1.docx and IsUnc is false, although the access was made via UNC. that's the issue...