# System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException : External component has thrown an exception

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-rest

I am working on a system that starts a web service. The code is effectively:

```
try
{
    var hostRESTDataService = new WebServiceHost(typeof(MyDataService));
    hostRESTDataService.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Created REST Data Service");
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
}
```

It is built on .NET 4 on Windows 8.1. We cannot upgrade it to 4.5.

Hundreds of installations work fine, but at the point of open(), one German PC gives (translated): "System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException : External component has thrown an exception".

Have looked at posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313853/how-should-you-diagnose-the-error-sehexception-external-component-has-thrown-a) and tried to get more info using [this post](http://dailydotnettips.com/2013/09/23/corruptedstateexceptions-in-net-a-way-to-handle/), but cannot find the answer.

Does anyone know how we can find a solution to this problem please?

Comment: could this be an issue with the German PC not having the necessary assembly's and or dll's installed on that machine.. is the correct version of .net framework installed on that machine.. it's really hard to determain without having more information in regards to the error that was being thrown..

Comment: Agree, but that is all the info we have. We had a look in the GAC/Folder it's running from and all dll's appear to be present.

Comment: yeah but what if the Dll's that are being used are not Gac'd this could be the case if the dll is set to copy local = false.. when it probably should be true.. but if the one machine is the only one that's not working I would still figure out a way to do a comparison in regards to what's on one that's working vs what's missing on the one that's not working..

Comment: Add the stack trace to the question, please.