# Idera, SQL safe giving the Following error, Started happening from no where?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, backup

Started getting this Error when I Execute the following code

```
DECLARE @Returncode int
declare @digitalLocation varchar(500)
set @digitalLocation = '\\MainFolder\SecondFolder\%database%_backup_%timestamp%.safe'
declare @location varchar(500)
set @location = 'D:\MainBackUpFolder\FullBackups\%database%\%database%_backup_%timestamp%.safe'
declare @DatabaseName varchar(300)

set @DatabaseName = 'Digital'
exec @Returncode = xp_ss_backup @database = @DatabaseName, @filename = @digitalLocation, @verify = 1
```

cant find anything on google, can anyone help?

```
xp_ss_backup did not complete.  An error(0,1) was encountered.  Please check the parameters and their values. [v4.9.605.3451]

SQLsafeCmd output:
------------------
SQLsafe Freeware Edition CLI Version 4.9.605.3451
Copyright (c) 2004-2008 BBS Technologies, Inc., All Rights Reserved.
<http://www.idera.com/>

Connecting to Backup Agent on SKYADMIN...success.  (4.9.605.3451)
Connecting to SQL Server SKYADMIN...success.  (9.0.5000.0 SP3+)

BACKUP digital...FAILED.
Server instance: SKYADMIN, Database: digital
External component has thrown an exception.

--- End of SQLsafeCmd output ---
```

Comment: Has this ever worked?

Comment: Nope, Still get the same error, not sure what happened, worked before without any problems

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1313853/1531971

Comment: `worked before without any problems` So what has changed? is the folder out of disk space? Is the UNC path still valid? Why are you setting `@location` and not using it?

Comment: Nothing has change that I'm aware of, folder has 86gb free thats more than enough, the path is still valid, @location is being used in the code below that I didnt include here.

Comment: Got it working by Updating the licence file,
http://community.idera.com/database-management/monitoring--performance/f/255/t/25374