# System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named '?' in DLL 'mip_dotnet'.' on CreateMipContext in Outlook VSTO add-in?

Tags: outlook-addin, microsoft-information-protection

I'm trying to initialize MIP in Outlook VSTO add-in, it failed with System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named '?' in DLL 'mip_dotnet'.' exception on MIP.CreateMipContext method.

```
   MipContext mipContext = MIP.CreateMipContext(appInfo,
                             "mip_data",
                             LogLevel.Trace,
                             null,
                             null);
```

I wonder if there is a way to integrate MIP protection API in Outlook VSTO add-in? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to the `Microsoft.InformationProtection.dll` assembly. Then you must call the [MIP.Initialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.informationprotection.mip.initialize?view=mipsdk-dotnet#Microsoft_InformationProtection_MIP_Initialize_Microsoft_InformationProtection_MipComponent_System_String_) method which loads the MIP dlls needed for UPE.

```
var subDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\" + (Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64SubFolder" : "x86SubFOlder");
  var factory = MIP.Initialize(MipComponent.Policy, subDir);
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I added the hard code path for x64 dll as there is no exist dll sub folder path under the addin assembly. 
It still got the same error. Is there anything I can try? Thanks a lot!



`
//var subDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\" + (Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86");
            var subDir = @"C:\Users\azadm\source\repos\OutlookAddIn1\OutlookAddIn1\bin\Debug\x64";
`

Comment: Update the status. I use process monitor tool to trace the file not found error. Then I copy all the x64 dll to the respective path. I got another error. System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: 'External component has thrown an exception.'

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313853/how-should-you-diagnose-the-error-sehexception-external-component-has-thrown-a .